# Как разбить строку на список в Python?

Tags: python

нужна помощь по Пайтону.
Есть ввод химической реакции при помощи input()

```
Reaction = input("")
```

Реакция задается в форме `aA + bB = cC + dD`
a b c d - коэффициенты (тип int)
A B C D - учасники реакции (str)
Как мне разделить полностью данный ввод при помощи функции split() или как нибудь по-другому, что бы получить список:

```
list = (a, A, b, B, c, C, d, D)
```

Вопрос решен! Спасибо большое за решение MarianD и Sergey

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных (в том виде как будет вводить пользователь)

Comment: Реакции могут быть разные, как пример - 4NH3 + 5O2 = 4NO + 6H2O;

Comment: Можно попробовать разобрать уравнение на токены с помощью методов, подобных тем, что используют интерпретаторы/компиляторы. Или конечный автомат, ожидающий лат.символы, цифры (коэффициенты и подстрочники),  скобки круглые и квадратные (для комплексных ионов), пробелы,+,=

Comment: А какой должен быть результат для `4NH3 + 5O2 = 4NO + 6H2O` ? Дополняйте ответами вопрос пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как мне разделить полностью данный ввод

Если ограничиться только двучленами с обоих сторон от знака равенства и запретить пробелы, то можно элементарно сделать через регулярные выражения:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python                                                                          

import re                                                                                         

regex = r'(\d+)(.+)\+(\d+)(.+)=(\d+)(.+)\+(\d+)(.+)$'                                             
s1 = '4NH3+5O2=4NO+6H2O'                                                                          
s2 = '4NH3+5O2=4NO+6H20'                                                                          

ro = re.compile(regex)                                                                            

result = re.findall(ro,s1)                                                                        
print(result)                                                                                     

result = re.findall(ro,s2)                                                                        
print(result)
```

Результат работы программы выглядит так:

```
[('4', 'NH3', '5', 'O2', '4', 'NO', '6', 'H2O')]
[('4', 'NH3', '5', 'O2', '4', 'NO', '6', 'H20')]
```

Answer (score 2):

После каждого шага я добавил `print()`, чтобы было ясно, что сделалось:

```
import re


def numrest(member):
    return (re.sub(r"(^\d+)", r"\1 ", member)).split()


formula = "4NH3 + 5O2 = 4NO + 6H2O"

list_ = re.split(r"\+|=", formula)
print(list_)

list_ = [el.strip() for el in list_]
print(list_)

list_ = [numrest(el) for el in list_]
print(list_)

list_ = [el[i] for el in list_ for i in (0,1)]
print(list_)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ['4NH3 ', ' 5O2 ', ' 4NO ', ' 6H2O']
> ['4NH3', '5O2', '4NO', '6H2O']
> [['4', 'NH3'], ['5', 'O2'], ['4', 'NO'], ['6', 'H2O']]
> ['4', 'NH3', '5', 'O2', '4', 'NO', '6', 'H2O']
> ```

Функция `numrest()`, применена в предпоследнем шаге, возвращает из строки пару (число, остаток), например из строки `"4NH3"` возвратит пару `("4", "NH3")`.

Comment: Тут весь вопрос, а не надо ли случаем еще `H20` дорезать на `['H', '2', 'O']`. Потому, что если надо, то проще будет регуляркой выбрать все числа и буквы и превратить строку в список из символов

Comment: @Viktorov, для общего вида вывода в вопросе - `list = (a, A, b, B, c, C, d, D)` - нет.